# How do i change the meta title in next.js 13?

Tags: next.js, meta-tags, next.js13, page-title

I created a next 13 project with manny subpages.
In next 13 i found the soloutin to do this with folders in the app folder like `app/contact/page.tsx`
I tried it and it worked so i can open the route with localhost:3000/contact
Now i am at the point where i want to change the meta title for the subpage but there is the Problem...
I cant add:

```
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Home | Sakura Hagen',
  description: 'Home Page of Sakura Hagen',
}
```

because iam using "use client" in my subpage so this is what i tried else.

First i tried importing head like this:

```
import Head from 'next/head';

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Contact - Page </title>
        <meta name="description" content="Willkommen zu meinem Blog" />
      </Head>....
```

but it changed nothing. It resultet with the title before.

Next i tried to

`npm i next-seo`

then i tried to import it like this

```
import { NextSeo } from 'next-seo';

<NextSeo
        title="Contact - Page"
        description="description"
      />
```

but nothing changed again...

last i tried to create a layout.tsx, where i add the meta like this:

```
import { Footer, Navbar, ScrollToTop, Tel } from '@/components'
import './globals.css'
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'contact - page',
  description: 'description',
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="de" className='scroll-smooth'>
      <body className="relative"> 
        <Navbar />
        {children}
        <Footer />
        <Tel />
        <ScrollToTop />
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

it worked a little bit, if i open my homepage and click on contact i go to .../contact with the new title. But if i try to jump back to main page the error looks like this.

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
```

Answer (score 1):

I already found an answer while formulating it, I hope it helps others

Its pretty simple...

Just use:

```
<title>Page title</title>
```

inside of the page.tsx

should look like this

```
import React from 'react'

const page = () => {
  return (
    <title>Page title</title>
    <div>page</div>
  )
}

export default page
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the App Router, there is no need to use the `<title>` element manually. If you check the [Next.js documentation on Metadata](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/metadata#merging), you will notice that there is merging in place along the segments.

For example, in my root layout at `app/layout.tsx`, I declare the following:

```
export const metadata = {
  title: {
    template: '%s — Showcasething'
  }
}
```

And within a page, such as `app/page.tsx`, I can do the following:

```
export const metadata = {
  title: 'Page Title'
}
```

What Next.js does is merge these exported `metadata` objects (or generated metadata from `generateMetadata`) to build the final metadata and, thus, the title. In my example, navigating to the root path at `/` will take the template of the root layout and slot in the page-specific title "Page Title" into it, resulting in "Page Title - Showcasething".

Of course, the same works without a template by using just a `title` along the segments to override them where applicable. Another example for this:

```
// app/layout.tsx
export const metadata = {
  title: 'Home'
}

// app/nested/page.tsx
export const metadata = {
  title: 'Nested'
}
```

This configuration will make the title of `/nested` be "Nested."

Answer (score 0):

```
export const metadata = {
  title: 'Page Title'
}
```

or

```
import Head from 'next/head'
 
function IndexPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>My page title</title>
      </Head>
      <p>Hello world!</p>
    </div>
  )
}
 
export default IndexPage
```

Not working if you use `"use client"` so you need to delete `"use client"` or just use tag : `<title>Page title</title>`